# Specify Jupyter server from VSCode fails with error

Tags: jupyter, vscode-extensions

I have Jupyter lab running on my machine. I'm able to work on notebooks and run cells in the browser.

I install the Jupyter extension in VSCode. Trying to run a cell in VSCode fails with the error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'notebookapp' from 'notebook' (~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py)
```

I try to change the Jupyter server (Specify Jupyter server for connections) and get the following VSCode error message (in a popup)

```
Command 'Jupyter: Specify Jupyter server for connections' resulted in an error (command 'jupyter.selectjupyteruri' not found)`.
```

How do I configure the VSCode Jupyter extension to use the Jupyter lab server?

Comment: The machine is a Mac. Sonoma 14.0.